# VueJs set active class, when One li element is clicked in dropdown using V-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

I can't figure out how to set active class in dropdown options, using v-for loop and one of the option is bold by default. On clicking other option, the active class should be added to the other option, making the clicked option bold and vice versa.

```
<div id="jobAid-menu" class="dropdown-content" v-if="openTypeView"> 
        <ul> 
          <li class="type-li-item" v-for="item in help" :id="item.liId" :key="item.id" :class="item.class"  @click="changeHelpType(item)">
          <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
          </li>  
        </ul>
     </div>
```

And below is my JS Code,

```
data(){
    openTypeView: false,
    active_id: 1,
    help: [
             
            {
              name: "Users",
              id: 1,
              liId: 'g1',
              class: 'active',
            },
            {
              name: "Profile",
              id: 2,
              liId: 'g2',
              class: '',
            },
          ],
},
    methods:{
     changeHelpType:function(item){
     if(this.active_id===item.id){
                  this.help.find(item => item.id === this.active_id).class='';
                  this.help.find(item => item.id===id).class='active' ;
                  this.active_id =id;
                  }
    }
    }
```

CSS Styling

```
li {
 font-weight:normal;
}

li.active {
  font-weight:bolder;
}
```

Now By default the first object in help array is active. if I click on other li element in the dropdown it should become active and all other li element should lose active class. Can you please help me out on how to do this. I'm a newbie in VueJS, ignore my mistakes if any.

Comment: You cannot have two class definitions on your li !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your data option should be a function that returns an object, second use a computed property based on `help` property to add `class` field :

```
data(){
   return{
    openTypeView: false,
    active_id: 1,
    help: [
             
            {
              name: "Users",
              id: 1,
              liId: 'g1',
              class: 'active',
            },
            {
              name: "Profile",
              id: 2,
              liId: 'g2',
              class: '',
            },
          ],
  }
},
computed:{
   customHelp(){
      return this.help.map(item=>{
        item.class= this.active_id===item.id?'active':''
                  return item;
            })
   }
}
```

then loop through that computed property :

```
 <li class="type-li-item" v-for="item in customHelp" :id="item.liId" 

:key="item.id" :class="item.class"  @click="active_id=item.id">
          <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
 </li>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added the loop through computed property. But still the active class isn't working. Initially, it is loading only the first option bold by default. On toggling, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try out `@click="active_id=item.id"` instead of `@click="changeHelpType(item)"`